# I can't play online on Battleblock Theatre

Tags: battleblock-theater

I can't play online on Battle Block Theater, as it says my profile does not have the correct permissions to play on XBOX Live. So, I was wondering, how should I fix this?

I already tried to fix it but, had no luck. Are the permissions on family settings on the account or profile? My Dad tried to fix it as well. He's saying that you need to pay to play online but I don't believe it.

Comment: Can you please utilize punctuations? I can barely read your question.

Comment: You should believe your dad. You need a Gold account (which means paying) to play anything online with an Xbox.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand of this issue, you either need to change the permissions on your user dashboard, or pay for the XBOX Live Gold membership service to play online multiplayer (if you don't already). Otherwise, you should be able to play online.